# Hacker friendly vacuum robots

Tags: roomba

I'm considering buying a vacuum robot.  At first I got excited at finding out that Roomba has an Open Interface.  Apparently this was taken out around model 800+ (?)   The newest models do not have an Open Interface.   What robot vacuums are open / hackable?

Comment: You can always pick up a used model of one of the older Roombas. They often come up fairly cheap on eBay.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense for the robotics part, except I was hoping to use this as an actual vacuum cleaner too.  The newer models are better at vacuuming.

Comment: possible duplicate of: https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/9495/what-irobot-products-support-the-open-interface-besides-the-irobot-create

Answer (score 3, accepted):

iRobot actually offers a robot geared toward developers/hackers, and is fairly affordable at $199: http://store.irobot.com/default/create-programmable-programmable-robot-irobot-create-2/RC65099.html?cgid=us&_ga=2.47072295.1402319966.1513450326-1687721061.1509919043

Comment: Looks like maybe it does not come with the "Cleaning Module". But this seems to still be a great way to get started and gets you something to get your hands on & get some satisfaction from. Parts for the Roomba are all over eBay, so you can gradually build yourself one that vacuums fairly well as you are able to afford the needed parts. I may get one of these myself!