# Turning a Roomba 980 into a Create

Tags: irobot-create

I have an old 980 that I want to turn into a Create.  Is this possible?

I've seen some posts that seem to indicate that it is, and I'm wondering if there are any more up to date instructions on how to do this.  I'm strong on the programming side, but not so much on the hardware side.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what  are some of the posts that you have seen?  ..... please add links to your question above

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, iRobot 900 series robots do not support the "Open Interface" spec that the Create uses.  It is only on 500, 600, 700, and 800 series models.  See this thread for more info: [What iRobot products support the open interface besides the iRobot Create?](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/9495/what-irobot-products-support-the-open-interface-besides-the-irobot-create)