# e6 Stock to Create Platform?

Tags: irobot-create

Can a new iRobot Roomba e6 (WiFi enabled, scheduling robot) be hacked like the iRobot Create, while allowing it to do a bit of vacuuming during non programming time?

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* TexasGEEK, but I'm afraid that it is not clear what you are asking. We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*, so it's a good idea to include details of what you want to achieve, what you tried, what you saw & what you expected to see. Please take a look at [ask] & [about] for more information on how stack exchange works and work through the [*Robotics* question checklist](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1302/37) to edit your question to make it clearer.

Comment: I think https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/18092/turning-a-roomba-980-into-a-create may answer your question (only 5xx - 8xx series are compatible with the Create 2 Open Interface). Please note that I am an iRobot employee, but the postings on this site are my own and don't necessarily represent iRobot's positions, strategies, or opinions.

Comment: Great answer @Steve.  Why not make it a real answer, and not a comment?

Comment: I don't think an "on hold" question can be answered. I took a pass at editing the question so that it would clarify the initial intent.

Comment: @Steve - You're correct; questions on hold can't be answered. I've opened the question back up, so please feel free to post your answer :)

Answer (score 1):

I think [turning a roomba 980 into a create](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/18092/turning-a-roomba-980-into-a-create) may answer your question; at this time, only 5xx - 8xx series are compatible with the Create 2 Open Interface.

<sup>Please note that I am an iRobot employee, but the postings on this site are my own and don't necessarily represent iRobot's positions, strategies, or opinions.</sup>